# how to prove that BFS directed-graph traversal algorithm is terminable?

Tags: algorithm

how to prove that BFS directed-graph traversal algorithm is **terminable**?
(I copy the pseudocode from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) )
Input: A graph G and a root v of G

```
  procedure BFS(G,v):
      create a queue Q
      enqueue v onto Q
      mark v
      while Q is not empty:
          t ← Q.dequeue()
          if t is what we are looking for:
              return t
          for all edges e in G.incidentEdges(t) do
             o ← G.opposite(t,e)
             if o is not marked:
                  mark o
                  enqueue o onto Q
```

Answer (score 0):

Every node is visited(marked) at most once, so at the worst case you will mark all nodes and then the algorithm will terminate.